# What does Death mean by "Sorry, not Sorry"?

Tags: bill-and-ted

In *Bill & Ted Face the Music (2020)*, Death says to Bill & Ted:

> Death: I have been demoted down here because I took two so-called
> "friends" back up who should not have gone back up. So, if that is why
> you're here...**Sorry, not sorry**.

What does Death mean by "Sorry, not Sorry"?

Answer (score 23):

This is a piece of slang that signifies that while an apology might be expected (due to social norms), the speaker does not really feel any regret.

Here's a [more thorough discussion](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/sorry-not-sorry/) from dictionary.com.  Important quote:

> *Sorry not sorry* is a sarcastic way of acknowledging that someone might not like whatever you're saying or doing ... but you don't really care.
>
> *Sorry not sorry* is a new take on a time-honored tradition: the insincere or ironic apology—as if to say *Sorry, but I’m not really sorry* or *Sorry, scratch that, I’m not sorry*.

Comment: Concur - to spell it out fully the unabbreviated phrase might be "I should feel sorry about this event, but I do not feel sorry."

Comment: I always considered the first part ("sorry") to express regret for to the second part ("not sorry"), and the second part ("not sorry") to refer to the topic at hand. In other words: "I regret to inform you that I don't feel sympathy for your current situation".

Comment: Reminds me of a game where one character said to the opponents: "Sorry, we had to win". And another told the opponents instead: "I'm not!"

Answer (score 5):

### Sorry, not sorry

This is a phrase used to indicate the speaker is not regretful in a situation they might be expected to be regretful in.

For reference, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sorry%20Not%20Sorry) <sub>(WARNING: Some mature topics discussed on this and other pages)</sub> says:

> 1. Typically used to signify that speaker does not care whether their behavior emotionally upsets someone else.
> 2. The term could also be used to acknowledge that the speaker's behavior could upset someone, but the speaker stands by their behavior.

With examples:

> 1. *Slaps book out of someone's hands* "Oh, you were reading that? Sorry Not Sorry."
> 2. In a cooking competition "I saw her drop her dish on the floor. I could have helped her, but I'm running out of time. Sorry Not Sorry."

In context, what the Reaper is saying is that he does not regret helping out Bill and Ted in the previous films.